# Android NDK build gives make error 6

Tags: android-ndk, gnu-make

Can't get Eclipse to build my NDK/JNI project.  Eclipse, or ndk-build from a command prompt, both give following output:

```
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8b/build/core/setup-app.mk:75: recipe for target `clean-installed-binaries' failed
make: *** [clean-installed-binaries] Error 6
```

What is "Error 6"?  I can't find any doc on that anywhere.  Helpfully, it doesn't say what the problem is, just giving the cryptic error code.

I found setup-app.mk and tried inserting something to echo the command it was executing, which was simply removing some files.  I copied and pasted it to the command prompt and it worked fine on its own:

```
rm -f ./libs/armeabi/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/lib*.so ./libs/mips/lib*.so ./libs/x86/lib*.so
```

Also tried inserting a "whoami" and it matched a whoami directly from the command prompt, so it's not acting as a different user with different permissions or something.

Been stuck on this for days.  Can anyone help?

Rob.

PS. I'm finding Eclipse/NDK/JNI almost impossible to work with.  It only seems to work for a week or two before falling in a heap again, seemingly with no change from me.  This one is now unusable until I fix this error.  I also have it installed on another machine, which is now also completely broken for completely different reasons.  How does anyone work in this environment?

Comment: You could try with [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) instead, much easier to use IMO, but I'm biased :)

Answer (score 0):

It's no miracle the actual command works: the error message comes from the **make** itself, which failed to generate the appropriate command!

Now what could have happened: most likely, you have some paths with spaces. Make sure that neigher eclipse, cygwin, project, workspace, nor ndk have spaces in their root paths.

Maybe, there is some problem with PATH. I refer to the environment variable in three environments: windows native, cygwin, and eclipse. Could it be that make you actually run is different from what you expect?

Note that you do not need cygwin to build with NDK 7 and higher, simply use **ndk-build.cmd**.